# cannot create div content dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

What is wrong here?

```js
var str = "
<div class='lorem'>lorem</div>
<br>
<div class='ipsum'>ipsum</div>
";

$('.parent').html(str);
```

```css
.parent{
width:50%;
margin:14px auto;
background:#eee;
}

.lorem{
cursor:cell;
background:gold;
}

.ipsum{
cursor:cell;
background:lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='parent'>

</div>
```

**Error:**

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token...`

lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum

Comment: Your str variable is wrong. After each line close quotes and add + or use `` instead of ""

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating multiline strings in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/creating-multiline-strings-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have line breaks in strings unless you use a template literal.

```
var str = "
  <div class='lorem'>lorem</div>
  <br />
  <div class='ipsum'>ipsum</div>
";
```

should be

```
const str = `
  <div class='lorem'>lorem</div>
  <br />
  <div class='ipsum'>ipsum</div>
`;
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

In the case that you don't want to use this (I don't know why you wouldn't), you could also do these:

```
var str = "<div class='lorem'>lorem</div>" + "<br />" + "<div class='ipsum'>ipsum</div>";

var str = ["<div class='lorem'>lorem</div>", "<div class='ipsum'>ipsum</div>".join("<br />");
```

```js
var str = `
<div class='lorem'>lorem</div>
<br>
<div class='ipsum'>ipsum</div>
`;

$('.parent').html(str);
```

```css
.parent{
width:50%;
margin:14px auto;
background:#eee;
}

.lorem{
cursor:cell;
background:gold;
}

.ipsum{
cursor:cell;
background:lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='parent'>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your string is in multi-line, either you have to use string concatenation (`+`) or use [`Template literals`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

***Using Template Literals:***

```js
var str = `
<div class='lorem'>lorem</div>
<br>
<div class='ipsum'>ipsum</div>
`;

$('.parent').html(str);
```

```css
.parent{
width:50%;
margin:14px auto;
background:#eee;
}

.lorem{
cursor:cell;
background:gold;
}

.ipsum{
cursor:cell;
background:lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='parent'>
```

***Using String Concatenation (`+`):***

```js
var str = ""+
"<div class='lorem'>lorem</div>"+
"<br>"+
"<div class='ipsum'>ipsum</div>"+
"";

$('.parent').html(str);
```

```css
.parent{
width:50%;
margin:14px auto;
background:#eee;
}

.lorem{
cursor:cell;
background:gold;
}

.ipsum{
cursor:cell;
background:lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='parent'>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = '<div class="lorem">lorem</div><br><div class="ipsum">ipsum</div>';
$('.parent').html(str);
```

```css
.parent{
width:50%;
margin:14px auto;
background:#eee;
}

.lorem{
cursor:cell;
background:gold;
}

.ipsum{
cursor:cell;
background:lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='parent'>

</div>
```